# android: APK installation failed... same package different signature

Tags: android, apk, signature

I'm working on two different computers with same Android Studio versions, settings and signature. The application is on Dropbox so I can access it from anywhere.

I get this error about APK having different signature when trying to work from the second computer.

Even worst, if I uninstall the APK and re-install from the second computer, the application doesn't behave as it normally does on first computer.

If I go back on first computer and install APK from there again, everything works as it should.

I'm a bit confused and clueless about what to do from here, so any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Comment: Are you signing your app with the same release key? Is the debug option enabled?

Comment: I believe so, as I generated my own signed APK for the app. If you are referring to the debug mode on the phone, yes it's enabled.

Comment: check this answer it works for me ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59530524/10148810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get this error about APK having different signature when trying to
>   work from the second computer.

When you install your app in debug mode(which I am guessing the case here is), android studio signs your apk with a debug key store. Every computer will have a different debug key store. That's why you can't install the app from different computer without uninstalling it first.

> Even worst, if I uninstall the APK and re-install from the second
>   computer, the application doesn't behave as it normally does on first
>   computer.

This is a different problem from the first one. You would have to more specific here. What is *normal* behavior. And what exactly is the deviation from that normal behavior.

Comment: At first I was using the default debug key but since the problem occurred, I tried generating my own signed APK hoping to solve this problem. I thought that by generating my own signed APK that it would always use that one instead no matter from which computer. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah I figured they might be two different problems. The normal behavior I was referring to is that I'm normally able to add items to a list (like an inventory) but after the APK is re-installed from the second computer, it doesn't work anymore. Validation of all my fields also stops working. You can find the full app as it is now (still in early development) here: https://github.com/sylvain-gdk/projet-Bracelet.git